# Custom Cover Flow Implementation in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

Instead of Images in coverflow, I want to have a list buttons in a scrollView(For each of the image in the coverflow), clicking upon them should navigate to the other page, which again contains a list of buttons inside scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) an open source library which accept UIViews as components :)

Hope this helps

Comment: This is fantastic, as it also allows custom animations.

Answer (score 0):

Use - https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/iphone/Classes/AFOpenFlow/AFOpenFlowView.m

And override the **touchesEnded** event in **AFOpenFlowView.m**

This might help you.